# How to customize the DatePickerDialog to show custom date in the text? - Swift

Tags: swift, nsdate, ios9, datepickerdialog

I am trying to change the date written inside the datePickerDialog to make Hijri Islamic date.

I found the function of showing the Hijri date as NSDateComponents

```
func hijriDate(dateToConvert: NSDate) -> NSDateComponents{
        let islamic = NSCalendar(identifier:NSCalendarIdentifierIslamicCivil)!
        let hijriComponents = islamic.components(NSCalendarUnit(rawValue: UInt.max), fromDate: dateToConvert)
        print("Date in system calendar:\(dateToConvert), in Hijri:\(hijriComponents.year)-\(hijriComponents.month)-\(hijriComponents.day)")
        return hijriComponents
        //"Date in system calendar:2014-09-25 09:53:00 +0000, in Hijri:1435-11-30"
}
```

So when the datePicker will print the date i wanna show the islamic component by converting the NSDate to Hijri Components.

So is there any way to show custom text for the datePickerDialog ? So I can use the function above to print out the date as Hijri from the NSDate ?

**UPDATE:**

The current [DatePickerDialog](https://github.com/squimer/DatePickerDialog-iOS-Swift) I use is this:

```
let STR_DATE_FORMAT = "EEEE d, MMM yyyy"

DatePickerDialog().show("Select date".localized(), doneButtonTitle: "OK".localized(), cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel".localized(), datePickerMode: .Date, defaultDate:self.data.event_date ) {
                (date) -> Void in
                self.data.event_date = date
                self.event_date.text = date.toString(format: .Custom(STR_DATE_FORMAT)) as String
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set calendar of the date picker as below,

```
  datePicker.calendar = NSCalendar(identifier:NSCalendarIdentifierIslamicCivil)!
```

Result looks like,

[image]

Comment: this will convert the date to hijti right after i choose it, i want the picker dates to be also converted, So that, while user picking the date, it should show the hijti one not only after choosing it.

Comment: Where you want to show? on DatePickerDialog it self? Just below select date title string?

Comment: not important to use datepickerdialog library, the important is to let user choose date as Hijri, not the normal date. so not only converting the date to hijti after use selecting date.

Comment: WOW, I was trying to find something like this, i cant wait till i test it when i get home

Comment: can you post the code u have used please ? did u modify the library itself ?

Comment: Yes. Added mention line after line self.datePicker.frame.size.width = 300.

Comment: I have last little question please, Can you show the calendar in different language as well ? like arabic

Comment: Use self.datePicker.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ar")

Comment: worked thank you so much, i did not expect it to be this simple. But i am new and i tried for couple of days with no result